# How do I make header-title stick to top?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to stick this header-title to the top. I want it to fill the top area as well as to the left & right. Can anyone with CSS-superskills please help?

Please note that I still want to keep the table-values in the middle, and I want to keep the table padding.

```css
#search input{
    width: 100%;
}

#activities {
    top: 0;
    float: right;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 2%;
    position: relative;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="activities">
                    <h2 style="background:#0094ff;color:white;width: 100%;padding: 4px;position: relative;">Div Title</h2>
                    <form id="search">
                        <input name="query" placeholder="Search...">
                    </form>
                    <table>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Fotboll 4v4
                        </td><td>
                            0.3 km
                        </td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td>
                            Brännboll
                        </td><td>
                            1.2 km
                        </td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td>
                            Badminton 2v2
                        </td><td>
                            1.5 km
                        </td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td>
                            Gruppmöte
                        </td><td>
                            2.2 km
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
```

Or demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/a2uqh6eu/

Comment: It is top already? you want it more up?

Comment: @DanielH i was thinking it should fill the top(to the right and left too)

Comment: ok check my updated answer. @Jesper

Comment: I will explain give me a min @Jesper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Div Title` did not take the whole width event you set it to 100% why? Because your container used padding, padding is the space of your content to the border, take a look at this link could help: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

So I removed your `padding: 20px` from the container, and added a class `.content` to wrap your content and add padding there:

```
.content {
  padding: 0 20px 20px; 20px
}
```

Now a class for your div-title with `margin-top: 0;` will let it stay top and `width: 100%;` will work now to take the whole width of the container. Also use `text-align: center;` to center the text.

```
.div-title {
  background: #0094ff;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```css
#search input {
  width: 100%;
}

#activities {
  top: 0;
  float: right;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: relative;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.div-title {
  background: #0094ff;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 20px 20px; 20px
}
```

```html
<div id="activities">
  <h2 class="div-title">Div Title</h2>
  <div class="content">
  <form id="search">
    <input name="query" placeholder="Search...">
  </form>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Fotboll 4v4
        </td>
        <td>
          0.3 km
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Brännboll
        </td>
        <td>
          1.2 km
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Badminton 2v2
        </td>
        <td>
          1.5 km
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Gruppmöte
        </td>
        <td>
          2.2 km
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use position:fixed; on your #activities div

To keep the table in the 'middle' as you put it, you'll probably need to take it out of the #activities div.

Answer (score 0):

```
#activities {
     padding-top: 0;
}

#activities h2 {
     margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, yes it fixes the top-distance, but it doesn't fill the header-title from left to right..

Comment: @Jesper this might require negative margin for the `h2`. e.g. `#activities h2 {margin: 0 -20px auto; }`, or wrap the rest of the content in a div with a margin, and lose the padding of the surrounding div

Answer (score 0):

You can use [position: sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example) property on your `#activities`.

Be careful, it is not implemented in [all web browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky). However, you can use [this polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill) : https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky for those that do not support the property.

Hope that help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... if I understand correctly, you want your DIV to stay at the top of the page always?

Try changing `position: relative;` to `position: fixed;`.
That may accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want remove the margin and padding to the `body` element add this to the css file

```
body { padding:0;margin:0;}
```

or just add position absolute to `activities` and `right:0`

```
#activities { position:absolute;right:0;}
```